# How this execute statement works in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I got a snip of a new execute statement in SQL Server 2012. after looking into it I have some confusion. Please have a look

```
 EXEC sproc_GETSTUDENT 
 WITH RESULT SETS 
 ( 
      ( 
             STUDENTROLLNO  INT,
             NAMEOFSTUDENT  VARCHAR(50)
      ) 
 );
```

What does this do?

Does it execute a stored procedure and populate the data in result table?

Result is a temporary table or CTE because with keyword is used. We know we use with keyword at the time of CTE. So please explain what will happen when the above snip run. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is documented in [EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) and is used to describe the result set.

In your case you will get two columns when you execute the statement. One `int` column called  `STUDENTROLLNO` and one  `varchar(50)` column called `NAMEOFSTUDENT`.

With this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sproc_GETSTUDENT AS
SELECT 1 AS C1, 'Pelle' AS X1
```

You will get

```
C1          X1
----------- -----
1           Pelle
```

if you execute the procedure using `EXEC sproc_GETSTUDENT`

But if you instead do

```
EXEC sproc_GETSTUDENT 
 WITH RESULT SETS 
 ( 
      ( 
             STUDENTROLLNO  INT,
             NAMEOFSTUDENT  VARCHAR(50)
      ) 
 );
```

you get a result set like this.

```
STUDENTROLLNO NAMEOFSTUDENT
------------- --------------------------------------------------
1             Pelle
```

Comment: could please tell me what is the meaning of RESULT SETS? is it like any temp table? thanks

Comment: @Thomas it is what you get when you do a select/query. A result set from a stored procedure comes from a select/query in the procedure. A stored procedure can have more than one statements and can therefor return more than one result sets.